# Network tags in web.config?

Tags: asp.net

i hae a doubt in my web application i place two network tags in smtp like this...

```
  <system.net>
      <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
          <network host="webmail.example.com" port="25" userName="info@example.com" password="asdf"  defaultCredentials="false"/>
          <network host="webmail.yyy.com" port="25" userName="info@yy.com" password="asdf12"  defaultCredentials="false"/>
        </smtp>
      </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
```

Comment: this is webconfig

<system.net>
      <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
          <network host="webmail.xxx.com" port="25" userName="info@xxx.com" password="asdf"  defaultCredentials="false"/>
          <network host="webmail.yyy.com" port="25" userName="info@yy.com" password="asdf12"  defaultCredentials="false"/>
        </smtp>
      </mailSettings>
    </system.net>

Comment: I AM GETTING THIS ERROR.
 The element may only appear once in this section. (C:\Inetpub\vhosts\XXX.com\httpdocs\web.config line 64)

Comment: when i am sending mail i am getting above problem (previous message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one SMTP Server in that section.  If you need to use two then you should probably store the information in the appsettings section of the web.config and set the appropriate values when you create the SMTPClient.